# Wordpress remove parent category in URL (Domain mapping)

Tags: wordpress, categories, slug

The following code allow me to remove parent category for my primary domain post. 
My problem is that I am using a third party plugin in order to map a second domain in my author name.

- domain1.com **PRIMARY DOMAIN**
- domain2.com **MAPPED DOMAIN**

Permalink structure :

- domain1.com/me/cat/subcat/postname => domain2.com/cat/subcat/postname

So basically, domain1.com/me MAP TO domain2.com and it's **Working good this way**

BUT if I remove cat slug and let only subcat like this (with the script) :

- domain1.com/me/subcat/postname **WORKING**
- domain2.com/subcat/postname **NOT WORKING** (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

**Script to remove parent slug in URL**

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_parent_category', 10, 3 );
function remove_parent_category( $permalink, $post, $leavename )
{
    $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if ( $cats ) {
        usort( $cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID' );
        $category = $cats[0]->slug;
        if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent ) {
            // Find parent categories and replace them in the link
            $parentcats = get_category_parents( $parent, false, '/', true );
            $permalink = str_replace( $parentcats, '', $permalink );
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at plugin like [WP remove category base](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-remove-category-base/) You might hook up to query_vars, category_link, request, category_rewrite_rules to accomplish that.